# How to know if destination page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, algorithm, web, request

I want to create an algorithm that redirect to certain page just when the destination page is fully loaded.

Example, I have a button that makes a redirect to for example: google.com.ar so I want to send a message by background (ajax or dont know what) to know when google.com.ar is loaded, after ok show google.

Is a thing to improve UX but also don't want to use blockUI cause I don't have it allowed in my company.

Any thought?

=) Thanks